# Vertical Scrolling in irregular shape div

Tags: html, css

I have a irregular shaped div

[image]

code as follows

```css
.block_left {
  background-color: red;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  border-right: 2px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}

.block_right {
  background-color: red;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
  border-left: 2px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.parent {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="block_left"></div>
  <div class="block_right"></div>
  <div class="div2" contenteditable="true">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut..."
  </div>
</div>
```

It is expanding if I type, but we want it in a fixed height, if I make it scrollable, it follows a "hard" limit on the horizontal length.

[image]

Is it possible to have a scrolling css/style property where it allows scrolling of unusual shapes?

Answer (score 3):

The only solution to make the div with text in it scrollable with the floating elements interacting with the text is to place the floating divs along with the text.

It messes up the borders, but you can't have both, specifically you will not be able to have the scrollbar on top of the right floating div

```css
.block_left {
  background-color: red;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  border-right: 2px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}

.block_right {
  background-color: red;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
  border-left: 2px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.parent {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div2" contenteditable="true">
    <div class="block_left"></div>
    <div class="block_right"></div>
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut..."
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work except you probably want to make the floated bits not editable.

Comment: @AHaworth maybe, I tried to delete them however with backspace or such but they stayed there. One thing you cannot have too is that the floating elements will scroll with the rest, of course, you cannot have them stay on top (makes sense)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the div is not shaped irregular at all. The div is a rectangle and behind the 'floating' items. You are hiding that fact by creating the blue borders for the red squares. The *only* thing happening is that the content of the div is actually working in your favor and not hiding behind the floating objects. I adjusted your CSS a little to prove my point.

Since not the content but the div itself is made scrollable the scrollbar would always hide behind the red squares. It won't shape around the red squares because that's just not how the style structure works. It would create a lot of potential bugs in other applications if that is how float and overflow would work together.

Short answer: it won't be possible. It is either full width or small but it won't flow like the textcontent does.

```css
.block_left {
  background-color: red;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.block_right {
  background-color: red;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  max-height: 120px;
}

.parent {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="block_left"></div>
  <div class="block_right"></div>
  <div class="div2" contenteditable="true">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut..."
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.div2[contenteditable] { outline: 0px solid transparent; }` for those who are looking for it.